# Getting Check IDs from JSTree - Get_Checked finds the nodes but not the ids

Tags: javascript, jstree

Apologies if this has been asked and answered before.  I've found a lot of posts that seem to answer the question but none of the solutions are working for me and I can't figure out why.

I'm using a JSTree (version 3) and have updated it to the latest version.  I have a div defined as follows:-

```
    <div id="ProductInterests">  
        <ul>
            @foreach (var productGroup in ViewBag.ProductGroups)
            {
                <li class="jstree-open">@productGroup.Name
                    <ul>
                        @foreach (var product in productGroup.Products)
                        {
                            if (Model.LeadProductInterests.Any(lpi => lpi.ProductID == product.ID))
                            { 
                                <li id="@product.ID" data-jstree='{"checked":true}'>@product.Name</li>
                            }
                            else
                            { 
                                <li id="@product.ID" data-jstree='{"checked":false}'>@product.Name</li>
                            }
                        }
                    </ul>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The tree is configured as follows:-

```
    $(function () {
        $("#ProductInterests").jstree
            ({
                core: { themes: { icons: false } },
                checkbox : { tie_selection : false },
                plugins: ["themes", "checkbox"]
            });
    });
```

This is producing html that looks like this:-

```
    <div id="ProductInterests">  
        <ul>
                <li class="jstree-open">Markiser
                    <ul>
                                <li id="1" data-jstree='{"checked":false}'>Terrassemarkise</li>
                                <li id="2" data-jstree='{"checked":false}'>Vindusmarkise</li>
                                <li id="3" data-jstree='{"checked":false}'>Semi-Nova</li>
                                <li id="4" data-jstree='{"checked":false}'>Dukskift</li>
                                <li id="5" data-jstree='{"checked":false}'>Fasademarkise</li>
                                <li id="6" data-jstree='{"checked":false}'>Kurvmarkise</li>
                                <li id="7" data-jstree='{"checked":false}'>Andre</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="jstree-open">Utv. Persienner
                    <ul>
                                <li id="8" data-jstree='{"checked":false}'>L50</li>
                                <li id="9" data-jstree='{"checked":false}'>Spesial</li>
                                <li id="10" data-jstree='{"checked":false}'>Variant</li>
                                <li id="11" data-jstree='{"checked":false}'>L80</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

That looks perfect in my UI and I'm able to check and uncheck nodes beautifully.

Then in my form submit I have this:-

```
    $("form").submit
    (
    function () {
        var checkedProductInterests = [];
        $("#ProductInterests").jstree("get_checked", true).forEach(function () {
            checkedProductInterests.push(this.id);
        });
        alert(checkedProductInterests.join(","));
    }
    );
```

From everything I can find on line that should output an alert showing all the selected ids but it's not.  It's outputting a list of blanks.  I can infer it's finding the nodes correctly because it returns the correct number of blanks (I count the commas) but the id is being returned as blank.

I've tried using this form: jstree("get_checked", false) and using this instead of this.id but that produces the same result.  I've also tried the form jstree(true).get_checked(true), same result again.

I assume there's something wrong with the way I'm setting the id on the nodes but it looks right to me.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you have the latest jstree version this should be enough:

```
$("#ProductInterests").jstree(true).get_checked().join(',');
```

Here is a demo (make a selection and click the button):
<s>http://jsfiddle.net/DGAF4/520/</s>
http://jsfiddle.net/DGAF4/521/

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

It doesn't look like the jsTree external resource is loading on that fiddle.  When I look at it it's not themed as a tree, no check boxes etc.  I took a look at a previous fiddle you gave me at http://jsfiddle.net/DGAF4/516/ and it has the same problem.  Broken link perhaps?

Meantime, that looks like what I've been trying but I'll have another go at it this evening.

Comment: That is because it tries to load JS from github directly. You can use this URL instead: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.1.1/jstree.min.js I updated my answer with the new fiddle.

Comment: Awesome, that worked a treat and proves the ids are there.  So the problem must be something to do with my bit of java script.  I should be able to figure that out on my own.  Thanks once again for your help.